# Алгоритмы определения видимости в 2D

Tags: алгоритм, разработка-игр, 2d

Дано: 2D пространство представленное в виде матрицы квадратов. Каждый квадрат в свою очередь матрица N на N точек.  Каждая точка пребывает в 2-х состояниях: прозрачна/не прозрачна. Точки образуют линии и геом. фигуры. Они могут пресекается друг с другом. Но при этом каждую линию и фигуру можно описать уравнением.

Подскажите "шустрые" алгоритмы определения видимости точки **K** в квадрате **P** из точки **Q** в квадрате **A**.

PS: Ищу именно "шустрые" варианты. Понятно, что можно "в лоб" перебрать все отрезки и фигуры на предмет пересечения луча видимости и если пересечений нет то видимость есть. Но линий и фигур может быть очень много, точек между которыми проверяется видимость тоже, а процессорное время на расчёт видимости ограничено.

Comment: Построить растровую карту и провести луч.

Comment: Т.е. по сути провести поточечную трасировку линии из точки A в точку Б попутно определяя видимость проходимой точки и если удалось добраться до Б не встретив непрозрачные точки то Б видима?
А само определение трассируемых точек и их обход и не будет ли по времени дольше чем проверка на пересечение линии видимости отрезками и фигурами из массива объектов поля?

Comment: Да, самое долгое что может быть так это поддерживать актуальность битовой растровой карты, особенно если эти фигуры имеют свойство меняться.

Comment: Мне пока вспоминается только https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visibility_polygon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала можно отбраковать квадраты, которые не имеют общих точек с линией центров QK. Для этого достаточно составить уравнение линии QK и проверять, совпадают ли знаки при подстановке всех углов квадрата в это уравнение.

Следующим этапом может быть построение описанных кругов для каждой из фигур. В этом случае возможна быстрая отбраковка фигур, расстояние от центра которых до прямой больше радиуса.

Просчёт видимости по оставшимся фигурам следует вести в порядке удалённости их центра от линии QK.